# Inserting the correct detail for parent records in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing the following script to be executed on SQL Server. I need to ensure that the correct foreign key records are mapped to the parent table. If you see below I am hardcoding the foreign key and assuming that sequentially it will execute and will be fine. I have around 100 plus records to be inserted. I need to know there is way to check the correct parent id before inserting the detail records.

Main table

```
insert into multilingual.OnScreenText (applicationcode,OnScreenTextCode)
values ('MASTERDATA','DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.FULL_LEGAL_NAME')
insert into multilingual.OnScreenText (applicationcode,OnScreenTextCode)
values ('MASTERDATA','DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.COMPANY_REGISTRATION_NUMBER')
insert into multilingual.OnScreenText (applicationcode,OnScreenTextCode)
values ('MASTERDATA','DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.TEXT')
```

Foreign table

```
insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue)
values (1,'en-GB', 1,'Full legal name')
insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue)
values (1,'fr-FR',0,'Nom légal complet')

insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue)
values (2,'en-GB', 1,'Company registration number')
insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue)
values (2,'fr-FR',0,'Numéro d''entreprise')

insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue)
values (3,'en-GB', 1,'To update your full legal name or company registration number please contact your Anglo American Relationship Manager')
insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue)
values (3,'fr-FR',0,'Pour mettre à jour votre nom légal complet ou le numéro d''enregistrement de votre société, veuillez contacter votre responsable des relations avec Anglo American.')
```

Comment: There are various ways of doing this. One simple approach is to insert a parent row, capture the identity value used for that row and then supply that value to the insert statements for the associated child rows. E.g., <insert parent>, <get scope_identity>, <insert child1>, <insert child2>, repeat as needed.

Comment: Your solution is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. Wrap it in a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I am hardcoding the foreign key and assuming that sequentially it
> will execute and will be fine."

A good approach assumes nothing.  In this case the DDL of the tables hasn't been provided but it seems likely the 'multilingual.OnScreenText' table has an integer primary key with the IDENTITY property.  If so then the inserted identity value could be accessed using the SCOPE_IDENTITY() function.

The request was for a script.  The following sets NO COUNT ON (to reduce messaging)
and sets XACT_ABORT ON to ensure any transaction rollback applies to all DML statements.  After each INSERT into 'multilingual.OnScreenText' the script tests to make sure a row was actually inserted (@@rowcount>0).  If a row was inserted, then the generated identity value is assigned to the @id variable and used in subsequent INSERTs to the 'multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation' table.  Something like this

```
set nocount on;
set xact_abort on;

begin transaction
    declare @id         int;

    insert into multilingual.OnScreenText (applicationcode,OnScreenTextCode) values
    ('MASTERDATA','DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.FULL_LEGAL_NAME');
    if @@rowcount>0
        begin
            select @id=cast(scope_identity() as int);

            insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue) values
            (@id,'en-GB', 1,'Full legal name'),
            (@id,'fr-FR',0,'Nom légal complet');
        end

    insert into multilingual.OnScreenText (applicationcode,OnScreenTextCode) values
    ('MASTERDATA','DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.COMPANY_REGISTRATION_NUMBER');
    if @@rowcount>0
        begin
            select @id=cast(scope_identity() as int);

            insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue) values
            (@id,'en-GB', 1,'Company registration number'),
            (@id,'fr-FR',0,'Numéro d''entreprise');
        end

    insert into multilingual.OnScreenText (applicationcode,OnScreenTextCode) values
    ('MASTERDATA','DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.TEXT');
    if @@rowcount>0
        begin
            select @id=cast(scope_identity() as int);

            insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue) values
            (@id,'en-GB', 1,'To update your full legal name or company registration number please contact your Anglo American Relationship Manager'),
            (@id,'fr-FR',0,'Pour mettre à jour votre nom légal complet ou le numéro d''enregistrement de votre société, veuillez contacter votre responsable des relations avec Anglo American.');
        end
commit;
```

Comment: I ran the above script. It has inserted the records in multilingual.OnScreenText but nothing in multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation. Just for your info , I added the declaration that was missing in the script  declare @@rownum int;

Comment: There was an error I corrected.  Initially the code had @@rownum (which was incorrect) and now it's been updated to @@rowcount.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Hard-coding the id values seems risky.  Assuming the schema exists and the tables are something like this...

```
create table OnScreenText (
  OnScreenTextId int identity(1,1) not null,
  applicationcode varchar(50),
  OnScreenTextCode varchar(128)
)

create table multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (
  OnScreenTextId int not null,
  LanguageCode varchar(50) not null,
  DefaultLanguage int not null,
  OnScreenTextValue varchar(1000)
)
```

...this should work...

```
insert into multilingual.OnScreenText (applicationcode,OnScreenTextCode)
values ('MASTERDATA','DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.FULL_LEGAL_NAME')
insert into multilingual.OnScreenText (applicationcode,OnScreenTextCode)
values ('MASTERDATA','DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.COMPANY_REGISTRATION_NUMBER')
insert into multilingual.OnScreenText (applicationcode,OnScreenTextCode)
values ('MASTERDATA','DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.TEXT')

insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue)
select ost.OnScreenTextId, 'en-GB', 1, 'Full legal name'
from multilingual.OnScreenText ost
where ost.OnScreenTextCode = 'DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.FULL_LEGAL_NAME'

insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue)
select ost.OnScreenTextId, 'fr-FR', 0, 'Nom légal complet'
from multilingual.OnScreenText ost
where ost.OnScreenTextCode = 'DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.FULL_LEGAL_NAME'

insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue)
select ost.OnScreenTextId, 'en-GB', 1, 'Company registration number'
from multilingual.OnScreenText ost
where ost.OnScreenTextCode = 'DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.COMPANY_REGISTRATION_NUMBER'

insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue)
select ost.OnScreenTextId, 'fr-FR', 0, 'Numéro d''entreprise'
from multilingual.OnScreenText ost
where ost.OnScreenTextCode = 'DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.COMPANY_REGISTRATION_NUMBER'

insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue)
select ost.OnScreenTextId, 'en-GB', 1, 'To update your full legal name or company registration number please contact your Anglo American Relationship Manager'
from multilingual.OnScreenText ost
where ost.OnScreenTextCode = 'DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.TEXT'

insert into multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation (OnScreenTextId,LanguageCode,DefaultLanguage,OnScreenTextValue)
select ost.OnScreenTextId, 'fr-FR', 0, 'Pour mettre à jour votre nom légal complet ou le numéro d''enregistrement de votre société, veuillez contacter votre responsable des relations avec Anglo American.'
from multilingual.OnScreenText ost
where ost.OnScreenTextCode = 'DETAILS.COMPANY_INFORMATION.TEXT'
;

select *
from multilingual.OnScreenText
;

select *
from multilingual.OnScreenTextTranslation
;
```

Answer (score -1):

- This could be done in postgres using CTE but unfortunately sql server doesn't support this.
- Apart from this what you can do is run this whole thing as a single transaction and that too only after performing a check that the last id in `OnScreenText` is exactly 1 less than the first value of `OnScreenTextId` in `OnScreenTextTranslation` table's data.
- Summary

  1. Make sure the child and parent record are in expected sequence
  2. Start a transaction
  3. Fetch current last value (basically max/latest id) of Parent table's id column
  4. if (value from 3 == (value of **parentId** from 1st record of child insert statement) **-1** )

     - execute insert
     - commit
  5. else rollback

Comment: Sorry I didnt follow

Comment: my bad, can you setup DB fiddle by any chance ?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support CTE? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @nicomp SQL server does not support things like parallel(parent/child) inserts via CTE which is something that works in postgres.

Comment: @HarshGundecha That would make life much easier when updating foreign keys.